# Compiling Apache with C++ compiler

Tags: c++, apache

Is it possible to compile Apache and its list of modules using a C++ compiler?
That would make addition of C++ modules easier too. Right now I am working on adding some C++ modules, but if Apache itself were compiled as a C++ binary, that would make life much easier.

Comment: Can you explain why compiling Apache with a C++ compiler would make this easier? What's the trouble writing your modules in C++ and linking against the standard Apache build?

Answer (score 4):

C++ and C are interoperable. You may link C++ code with C code and vice versa (although C++ methods called from C must be declared `extern "C"` so as to not be *mangled*, and you lose the overloading which name mangling provides).

In fact, in the days when dinosaurs roamed the Earth, C++ compilers just emitted C and passed it down to a C compiler.

So, in a sense, you're already compiling Apache using a C++-compatible compiler (although its source is not C++): you shouldn't have any trouble at all writing a module as C++ and linking it in.

Comment: I understand, that it is not difficult to write c++ module for apache, but when I want to use the c++ features I end up having to write quite a bit of wrapper functions.

Comment: @user1059298 You cannot magically produce C++ from nothing. Since Apache is written in C, just compiling it with a C++ compiler wouldn't cause it to take use of the new language features like classes...

Comment: oops... I wasn't very clear in my previous comment. I see that now. when I want to use the c++ features (in my module)* I end up having to write quite a bit of wrapper functions.